# Using tal macro in Chameleon

Tags: plone, chameleon

I'm a Plone user and I've been using tal macros from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile for quite a while and created a library of existing macros and templates.

I started using chameleon page templates through grokcore.chameleon 1.0.3, and would like to keep using them within the existing framework. I.E. I want to be able to import tal macros and then fill out macro slots using chameleon.

So far I tried several ways of importing existing macro but none of them worked. 'Load' keyword isn't enabled even though Chameleon 2.14 is installed[1].

I've been looking for a compatibility layer, but all I've found so far is z3c.pt, which purpose is to speed up .pt page rendering and not provide compatibility layer.[2]

Are there any packages that activate tal macro and then insert information from a Chameleon page template?
As a workaround I can render tal template, render chameleon template and then do string substitution, but there's got to be someone who solved this problem in a more elegant way.

[1] [how to use macros with pyramid / ZPT (Chameleon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928186/how-to-use-macros-with-pyramid-zpt-chameleon)

[2] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.pt

**Update**
As a workaround I create a function that generates an intermediate page, which accepts html generated by chameleon page template.

**common.py**

```
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserView
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile

def insert_into_master(html, view):

    class View(BrowserView):
        def __call__(self):
            self.data = html
            return ViewPageTemplateFile('pt/master_holder.pt')(self)

    rendered = View(view.context, view.request)
    return rendered()
```

**pt/master_holder.pt**

```
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master"
i18n:domain="Plone"
xml:lang="en"
lang="en">

<div
    metal:fill-slot="main"
    tal:content="structure:view/data"
/>

</html>
```

**any client view that uses chameleon**

```
from five import grok
from zope.interface import Interface
from grokcore.chameleon.components import ChameleonPageTemplate

from common import insert_into_master

class MyView(grok.View):
    grok.context(Interface)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.name('myview')

    def render(self):
        view = ChameleonPageTemplate('<div>Hello, world!</div>')
        return insert_into_master(view.render(self), self)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chameleon's represents macros internally in a different form than Zope's standard page template implementation, and the two are not compatible. So you can only use Chameleon macros from other Chameleon templates.

You can try installing five.pt, which monkeypatches Zope to use Chameleon for all page templates.

Comment: I tried using z3c.pt to parse existing main_template.pt page with chameleon parser so I could load macro from it, but I got way too many parse errors I don't want to deal with. As a temporary solution I created old-style BrowserView page with older template where I insert chameleon-generated html as a structure.